# Oracle database, update data from 1 table to another

Tags: sql, sql-update, oracle12c

I have 2 tables in an oracle 12c database and i want to update from 1 table to the next.

Table 1 (EMBLEMTEMPLATE et):
et.emblemtemplate_id, et.customer_id, et.code

Table 2 (PRODUCTLISTPERCUSTOMER):
plpc.productlistpercustomer_id, plpc.customer_id, plpc.emblemtemplate_id,

What i am trying to do:

1. Check with all the plpc.productlistpercustomer if there is a plpc.emblemtemplate_id filled, if not this need to be updated.
2. plpc.emblemtemplate_id needs to be updated with et.emblemtemplate_id where et.code  = "999991"
3. The tables must be joined on CUSTOMER_ID

i created a select:

```
select plpc.customer_id,
  plpc.productlistpercustomer_id,
  plpc.emblemtemplate_id,
  et.customer_id,
  et.emblemtemplate_id,
  et.code
  from productlistpercustomer plpc
  inner join emblemtemplate et
  on et.customer_id = plpc.customer_id
  where et.code = '999991'
```

Can somebody help me to translate this to a sql update script?

Thanks!

[Visual of what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSJ9q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using an update with a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE
    productlistpercustomer plpc
SET
    emblemtemplate_id = (SELECT et.emblemtemplate_id
                         FROM emblemtemplate et
                         WHERE et.customer_id = plpc.customer_id AND
                               et.code = '999991')
WHERE
    emblemtemplate_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

How about `merge`?

```
MERGE INTO productlistpercustomer p
     USING emblemtemplate e
        ON (e.customer_id = p.customer_id)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET p.emblemtemplate_id = p.emblemtemplate_id
           WHERE     e.code = 999991
                 AND p.emblemtemplate_id IS NULL;
```